# Can R be an Indexing set?

Tags: order-theory

I was questioning my teacher about index sets and family of sets when he said " we could take our index set to be R also". Now from what i know( i am new to set theory and am studying Family of sets), i use indexing to arrange/ number the sets in a given collection( basically creating an one to one correspondence between the index set and the collection).So far i have encountered the set of natural numbers N being used as an index set for finite and infinite family of sets. My question is how can i use real numbers set R as an index set when it contains negative numbers?  what about the negatives?

Comment: What if we declare the time $t_0$ to be "now"?  In that case, perhaps we'd consider "one day from now" to be $t_1$, "one day ago" to be $t_{-1}$, "twelve hours from now" to be $t_{.5}$, and "pi days ago" to be $t_{-\pi}$.

Comment: "*how can i use real numbers set R as an index set* **when it contains negative numbers**"  That is your complaint?  Not the fact that it was uncountable?  "*isn't the whole point of indexing arranging the sets form least to largest*" No.  An index set merely is there so that we have an unambiguous way of labeling and using a label of an element that we were interested in.  It shouldn't bother us that negatives are allowed.  It shouldn't even bother us that the set is uncountable (*though that does add its own complications in certain applications of using it as an index set*)

Comment: **Theorem.** Any set can be an index set. *Proof.* Let $X$ be a set. Consider the indexing of $X$ as $X=\{x_i:i\in X\}$ where $x_i=i$ for all $i\in X$.

Comment: @user10478 i liked your simple explanation. it makes it clear where i was thinking wrong. Thankyou.

Answer (score 1):

*Any* non-empty set can be an indexing set. You can for instance, define, for every $t\in\Bbb R$, $I_t=(-\infty,t)$. There is no problem with that.

Comment: Why "non-empty"?

Comment: For no logical reason, but it would look a bit strange.

Comment: Yet, it occurs frequently enough.  E.g. "empty products" and "empty sums" can be said to have index-set $\emptyset$.

Comment: Let's not send the poor OP into the corner screaming in despair, shall we.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought experiment.  While thinking about it consider what you intuitively and linguistically consider the word "index" to mean.

Suppose we want to index all the points of a circle.  That if a circle is centered at $(2,3)$ and has radius $4$, and we want to index all the points $(x,y)$ of the circle based what the interior angle is.  So $p_0 = (6,3)$ which is the first point with an interior angle of $0$.  And $p_{\pi} = (-2,3)$ is the point where the angle is $\pi$ and $p_{\frac \pi 2} = (2,7)$ and $p_x = (2+4\cos x, 3+4\sin x)$.

That's an uncountable number points all indexed based an a criteria.  Is that an index?  Why or why not?  We haven't (and *can't*) index the points into a list where we can list them all one after another.   But you *have* indexed them so that we can "look up" any point based on its angle.

Is that what "index" means?[1]

Is it an index any different than a function?  Either in any practical sense or usage.[2]

====

[1] in my opinion, yes.

[2] in my opinion, there is no practical difference-- they are both a one way mapping of a set to another set  but  usage an index is specifically for reference and referral; a function is flexible in its purposes and goals.

oh, I suppose an argument can be made as the points of a set are distinct that an index must be an injective map... and technically a function is a collection of the input/output *pairs* and a value's "index" refers specifically only to the *input* referrer.  So they are different I suppose.

But a for any indexed set $B$ then $f:(indices\ of\ B) \to B$ via $i \mapsto b_i$ is a function.  ANd for any bijective function $f:A \to B$ then setting $b_i = f(i)$ is an indexing of the set $B$.

Yeah.... that's my answer and I'm sticking to it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concrete simple example. For every $r\in\mathbb{R}$, define a family of functions $(f_r:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R})_{r\in\mathbb{R}}$ by $f_r(x)=x+r$